# How to connect multiple html pages in one wordpress theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have multiple HTML pages i.e home, contact, about us etc. I have successfully created the Home page for WP theme but cannot connect other pages with the home.
I also want the header and footer same as for the other pages like my welcome page.

Comment: You must create a basic theme,and take the advantage of child themes.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have created the first page(index page) using the tutorials. There are tabs of other pages on it. But when I click on it it shows HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Do I have to create multiple index.php,header.php.footer.php for all the other html pages ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development,

Comment: The best way is to use a basic theme and customize as you wish, I wouldnt try and make a theme from scratch unless you know what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

For the header and footer to be the same across all pages, you want to edit header.php and footer.php. [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Document_Head_.28header.php.29) .

To get from the home page to other pages, you will need to configure the menu, under Appearance > Menus. You will then have to display this menu in a position within your header.php (or footer, why not).

And to style each page differently, you may want to look into [Page Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/), which will allow you to modify the look of each page individually, without resorting to a child theme.